# Can't redirect to url by javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I need a button, which lead up in url path like this:

from `/host/elements/1`
to   `/host/elements`

I have a link in my html:

`<a href="javascript:go_backward()"> </a>`

And a javascript function:

```
function go_backward() {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var page = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'))
    window.location.assign(page);
    return false;
}
```

But when i click the button i only get desired url printed, without correct redirect.
Why cat it be so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
window.location.assign(page);
return false;
```

to

```
window.location.href = page;
```

If you just want to go back you can also use:

```
window.history.go(-1)
```

Comment: Can't use go(-1) because of logic of the site, user is able to go back too many times, while need to return to certain page every time.

Thx for the answer!